# Are Hamilton equations for coordinate difference $q_i-q_j$ equivalent to ordinary ones?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, integrable-systems

From Lax pair equations:
$$\dot{L}=[L,M];\quad L_{i j}=p_i \delta_{i j}+\nu\left(1-\delta_{i j}\right) \frac{1}{q_i-q_j};$$
$$M_{i j}=d_i \delta_{i j}-\nu\left(1-\delta_{i j}\right) \frac{1}{\left(q_i-q_j\right)^2}, \quad d_i=\sum_{k \neq i} \frac{\nu}{\left(q_i-q_k\right)^2} .$$
for Hamiltonian:
$$H=\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{p_i^2}{2}-\nu^2 \sum_{i<j}^N \frac{1}{\left(q_i-q_j\right)^2} .$$
I proved that
$$\dot{p_i}=-\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial q_i};\quad \dot{(q_i-q_j)}=p_i-p_j
$$
The first identity is obviuos Hamilton equation for momentum, but second one is weaker that ordinary $\dot{q_i}=p_i$. Can I prove that from $ \dot{(q_i-q_j)}=p_i-p_j$?

Comment: What are you asking? Whether you can subtract the "trivial" Hamilton's equations among variables?

Comment: I am clearly asking if I can prove $\dot{q_i}=p_i$ from $\dot{(q_i-q_j)}=p_i-p_j$

Comment: What’s wrong with Hamilton’s equations?

Comment: nothing, I just have not to use them and get them from Lax pair

Comment: Should be stated in the question...

Comment: What exactly? It's obvious what am I asking from last two sentences

Comment: To you, not to your readers, obviously...